# SQL - Replace links and style between <a> </a>

Tags: mysql, sql, replace, str-replace

One of our websites has been hacked - sql injection.

The hacker has added links inside article text like the folowing:

```html
<a href="http://xxxxxxxx.net/" style="text-decoration:none;color:#676c6c">click</a>
```

Now, the idea is that we have been able to identify all of the URLs that were inserted, but the problem is that the link text (in this example 'click') is always random.

How can i run the sql replace function and just replace everything between random text and

Basically i want to clear this link completely.

Thank you

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest He said "click" is an example.

Comment: Search the Internet for a regexp replace UDF. MySQL doesn't have this built in.